# Default Checkbox to checked on Contact Page

Tags: inline-visualforce

When a contact page is opened i automatically want to check a checkbox "Do Not Call" to checked. This needs to be checked only for 1 recordtype & not others.
please suggest a solution or example code for this.

Few options i considered are:

1. workflow rule to update this checkbox - doesn't fit becoz user needs
       ability to uncheck if he wants
2. trigger to update this checkbox. - doesn't fit again because of same reason as above.
3. wrote a inline vf page and added to contact layout and hide it. Below is the code: Issue i am facing here is, i am not able to get the id of the field "Do Not Call". What is the fix for this (or) is there any better solution for this?

   ```
   <apex:page applyBodyTag="true" applyHtmlTag="true" showChat="false" showHeader="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Contact">
   <html> 
       <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               window.onload = function ()
               {                                    
                   document.getElementById("Do Not Call").checked = true;                 
               };
           </script>
       </head>   
       <body>

       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: The checkbox isn't actually a checkbox until you are in edit mode, and visualforce pages don't show in edit mode.

Comment: Why don't you create a workflow which will fire on create will mark check box as checked, then user can do anything with that check box because you have created workflow on create.

Comment: not sure why the question was down-voted & by who? concerned person - plz explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally a teammember came up with this approach: override create new action with a visualforce page. This visualforce page calls an extension which checks the recordtype and constructs the url with the field id of "Do Not Call" = true & returns the url as a page reference. works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some trick with Apex to mark the check box. Create a visual force page with action="{!MyActionMethod}" in apex:page.

VF page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="FunwithApex" action="{!MyActionMethod}">
<html> 
    <head>

    </head>   
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
Public Class FunwithApex{

    public FunwithApex(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


List<Contact> con = New List<Contact>();
 public void MyActionMethod()
   {

   con = [SELECT id, DoNotCall FROM Contact Where id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

   For(Contact contacts : con){

   contacts.DoNotCall = true;


   }

     Update con;

   }




}
```

Every time you will reload the page calls the MyActionMethod and update the donotcall check box. Place the VF page on Contact Page layout as hidden.

Comment: Thanks for posting., but in this approach, the user will not get the flexibility to uncheck the Do Not Call checkbox, if he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you might be using specific users ==> Try using `<apex:outputfield value="{!'field'}" rendered="{!'here exclude users who can check the box'}">` and `<inputcheckbox selected = "true" rendered="{!'same way around include users'}>"`

Comment: Thanks for posting. I am using the standard page and not a custom visualforce page.